# How to create folders based on chapter and move all the associated files under that folder while html transformation in DITA OT

Tags: xslt, ant, dita, dita-ot

I am transforming DITA xml to html using DITA-OT 3.4.1. What I am trying to do is  while transforming create folders based on chapter names and move all converted html files and images under individual chapter folder. Currently I am getting all html and images in the same folders. How can I achieve this using xslt or ANT

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bookmap PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA BookMap//EN" "bookmap.dtd">
<bookmap>
  <booktitle>
    <mainbooktitle>Title of the docuemnt</mainbooktitle>
  </booktitle>
  <chapter href="chapter1.xml">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>chapter 1</navtitle>
    </topicmeta>
    <topicref href="topic1.xml">
      <topicmeta>
        <navtitle>topic 1</navtitle>
      </topicmeta>
    </topicref>
    <topicref href="topic2.xml">
      <topicmeta>
        <navtitle>topic2</navtitle>
      </topicmeta>
    </topicref>
  </chapter>
  <chapter href="chapter 2.xml">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>chapter 2</navtitle>
    </topicmeta>
    <topicref href="topic1.xml">
      <topicmeta>
        <navtitle>topic1</navtitle>
      </topicmeta>
    </topicref>
  </chapter>
</bookmap>
```

my sample bookmap

Comment: I am not really familiar with DITA but in oXygen a sample bookmap project from the beginning has subfolders for topics and tasks so perhaps your input structure is too flat and you should reorganize your files into subdirectories, then perhaps the transformation result to HTML will reflect that structure.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't know the questioner's running environment. But almost heavy DITA user uses CCMS as their platform. Once CCMS checkout the DITA contents into the file system, it is usually the flat structure. All of the topics, ditamaps and images exist in the same folder. Rahul, are you using CCMS for your DITA contents?

Comment: Yes, I am using CCMS.

Comment: I don't see a relation to Apache ant in this question. can yo

Comment: DITA-OT 3.5 added https://www.dita-ot.org/3.5/topics/plugin-rewrite-rules.html to rewrite file names and directories during preprocessing. If you are able to upgrade to 3.5, you would only have to configure the behaviour instead of needing to implement it yourself from scratch.

Comment: Thank you Jelovirt. I will try with your suggestion.

Comment: Will this work in DIAT OT3.4.1? I could not see any preprocess2 in 3.4.1

Comment: @jelovirt Does "rewrite fine names" work properly for about xrefs between DITA topics? Or is it user's responsibility to handle xref/@href attribute?